# Plot more than data frame on the same figure pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a list of many aggregated data frames with identical structure.

I would like to plot two columns from each dataframe on the same graph.

I used this code snippet but it gives me a separate plot for each dataframe:

```
# iterate through a list
for df in frames: 
    df.plot(x='Time', y='G1', figsize=(16, 10))
    plt.hold(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have each set indexed, you can just concatenate all of them and plot them at once without having to iterate.

```
# If not indexed:
# frames = [df.assign(sample=i) for i, df in enumerate(frames)]
df = pd.concat(frames).pivot(index='Time', columns='sample', values='G1')
df.plot(figsize=(16, 10));
```

This helps make sure that your data is aligned and `plt.hold` is deprecated in matplotlib 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) is not affected by matplotlib's `hold` parameter because it creates a new figure every time. The way to get around this is to pass in the `ax` parameter explicitly. If `ax` is not `None`, it tells the `DataFrame` to plot on a specific set of axes instead of making a new figure on its own.

You can prepare a set of axes ahead of time, or use the return value of the first call to `df.plot`. I show the latter approach here:

```
ax = None
for df in frames:
    ax = df.plot(x='Time', y='G1', figsize=(16, 10), ax=ax)
    plt.hold(True)
plt.show()
```